# Is simple forward proxy different than port forwarding?

Tags: networking, proxy, port-forwarding, squid, http-proxy

**Here is the introduction:**

I have a windows server which recently I decided to use it as a personal proxy server(not using ssh) like those free IP:Port proxies.

I've made my googling and it seems there are a lot of softwares like Squid,CCProxy,... that does this job but with extra features like caching, authentication,filtering and etc.

I also noticed that you can actually forward a request from a specific port to another destination:port using "netsh interface portproxy" in windows.

**So Here is the question:**

Can you setup a very simple proxy server(with nothing just sending the request through a server) with just port forwarding? Consider following cases:

1- I make a request in my browser on the server to google.com. Browser takes a free port in system and uses it to send the header request to a gateway or somewhere and finally to the destination.

2- I have setup a dummy proxy in my client(home!) browser with the IP address of server and port lets say 5555. Now i try to open google.com on my computer. On the server side we have port 5555 open and a port forwarding that forwards any income on 5555 to that mysterious destination that browser in the first case sends its request.

**How are these two cases different?**

I'm just trying to understand the concept here (sorry if it sounds stupid! ) and would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: this may be of interest to you  for learning http://superuser.com/questions/765165/tunneling-traffic-when-local-port-is-random but i think you are talking about web/http proxy specifically

Comment: an ssh socks proxy would do http and https and do no caching.

Comment: You write "I have a windows server which recently I decided to use it as a personal proxy server(not using ssh) like those free IP:Port proxies."  <--- you don't want an IP:PORT proxy, like kmint or that netsh command, you want an http/https proxy.    And to use the word "personal" is nonsense. Of course ssh can be used for your "personal" use.. You should state why you don't want to use `ssh -D 1234` (since you say you don't want to use ssh). Maybe you were unaware how easy that particular requirement was with ssh.

Comment: The differences between application proxies, Tunnels, and Port forwarding are myriad. Proxies operate at the application layer, and proxy protocol commands, whereas port forwarding and tunneling are all about simple port mapping and are concerned exclusive with the IP connectivity between two end points. They know nothing about the application in question.

Comment: if you went to a non http / non https / non socks  proxy, it'd only be able to send you to one IP / ( websites hosted on that one IP, which may just be one website) .

Comment: @FrankThomas well in a sense , or technically, even an application layer protocol like http doesn't care what the application is, whether it's chrome or firefox ;-)  they're just called application layer protocols. But if anywhere they are "below" the application. and wouldn't really be said to "know about" the application

Comment: the application is HTTP and it cares very much whether the `CONNECT` verb is used. HTTP implements specialized verbs for proxing, that allow application layer proxies. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt HTTP proxy has nothing to do with the network per se  but everything to do with how the HTTP command sequence is relayed through another host.

Comment: @barlop Thanks. Yes, I'm referring to HTTP/S proxy and I'm aware of the ssh -D solution. As I mentioned in the last paragraph, I'm just trying to understand the logic here.  Lemme rephrase it what a simple http proxy does beyond the scene?

Comment: @barlop Just to mention where the confusing part raised. I read this article :I saw an article

Comment: @barlop Just to mention where the confusing part raised. I read this article: http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/ about port forwarding and at the end he mentioned forwarding 5555 port request to CNN website so I wanted to know what a software like tinyproxy does more than this in the core not features)

Comment: @FrankThomas yes exactly. What it takes to be a middle man proxy server more than just chaining the ip of original sender and the destination with its own ip? if that makes sence!

Comment: There are a few ways to learn about that.. Have  2 computers.  Install Wireshark - may as well do so on both, it is a packet sniffer. Run an HTTP Proxy. (not https, try http proxy first).   And not a SOCKS proxy. You want to learn plain HTTP proxy(at least first anyway).  Install curl or wget,  these can make requests to an http proxy very cleanly.  Try curl and wget pointing to an http proxy. Watch on wireshark and learn about the http protocol.  Run cygwin and `nc -l 1234` (so just a server that outputs what it receives). And connect to that as if it is an http proxy.

Comment: and then it will send the http headers to that nc server / echo that you made..run the actual http proxy too watching A)What is received by the http proxy and B)What it sends out.The simple fact is that a web browser is a lot like the input for an http proxy.You give the http proxy an http address and it will access that http server.Accessing an https server is quite different to an http server.A question though, is is there any http proxy online that doesn't do caching?! But if you get a really small  one that does caching,there's no down side. ccproxy one may cache but is small and fine.

Comment: Also, something  I learnt recently which shocked me, because I was misled somewhat by http proxies that i'd installed.. But I discovered this when I started looking into programming with servers..   Was that when you go to an HTTP server and make a request,  It doesn't have to reply with a file, it could just reply with a string like "abc"..  And when you say http://www.blah.com/index.htm  it's not requesting a file it's requesting a "resource" which could be file or could just be an identifier for the http server program to send anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39191/discussion-between-barlop-and-codedme).